How can I convert *big.Rat to decimal256.Num correctly in Go?
I need to convert a number of type *big.Rat https://pkg.go.dev/math/big#Rat to the type decimal256.Num https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/apache/arrow/go/v16@v16.1.0/arrow/decimal256#Num.
For example, there is a function FromBigInt https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/apache/arrow/go/v16@v16.1.0/arrow/decimal256#FromBigInt. big.Rat has a numerator of type *big.Int https://pkg.go.dev/math/big#Rat.Num.
So it could be something like
func convert(ratNum *big.Rat) decimal256.Num {
    return decimal256.FromBigInt(ratNum.Num())
}

But what should I do with the denominator https://pkg.go.dev/math/big#Rat.Denom?
What is the correct conversion in the end?

"What is the correct conversion in the end?" That depends mostly on what you consider "correct" in those cases where a Num cannot represent a Rat. For the simple cases just convert numerator and denumerator and Div.

It depends what “correct” means to you, but one option would be:
var ErrNumberTooLarge = errors.New("number too large for decimal256")

func RatToDecimal256(x *big.Rat, scale int) (decimal256.Num, error) {
    var f, s, h big.Float
    var i big.Int
    s.SetFloat64(math.Pow10(scale))
    h.SetFloat64(0.5) //nolint:mnd

    f.SetRat(x).Mul(&f, &s)
    if f.Signbit() {
        f.Sub(&f, &h)
    } else {
        f.Add(&f, &h)
    }
    f.Int(&i)

    if i.BitLen() > 255 { //nolint:mnd
        return decimal256.Num{}, ErrNumberTooLarge
    }

    return decimal256.FromBigInt(&i), nil
}

Try it on the Go Playground.
    f.SetRat(x).Mul(&f, &s)

converts the number into an big.Float and adjusts for scale. Since we truncate to change the number into an integer we add 0.5 for rounding:
    if f.Signbit() {
        f.Sub(&f, &h)
    } else {
        f.Add(&f, &h)
    }

If you want a different rounding mode, adjust that part. Then we truncate to big.Int and finally decimal256.Num. Performance could be optimized by making h static and using a table for s, but the basic idea should be clear.
